# Use regexp_replace when are dots at the text

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to use regexp_replace to clean all ".com/.net/..." url ends (there's a list of texts I need to filter) from a column of text type, but I don't get success,

---

I got stucked at the following query:

```
SELECT id, url, regexp_replace(url, '.com|.net', '', 'g')
from companies;
```

Sometimes it gets more characters than it should.
Eg:

```
 1831 | network_company.net | work_company
```

It should return network_company, because I wrote .com, with a dot at the expression.

Comment: Try escaping the dot (.) e.g. ```select regexp_replace('network_company.net','\.com|\.net|\.co|\.org','');```

Comment: Another option - if you don't want to write the all extensions manually, you can use:  `SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('network_company.net  network_company.com  network_company.org network_company.business ','\.([[:alpha:]]){1,}','','g')` - this is removes all variants (.com1, .business and etc.)

Comment: The solution of @RaminFaracov is very interesting too, was the one I used.